# Requests ignores invalid proxy

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

I'm learning to use proxies in making requests, but I've run into a big issue, which is primarily that it seems `requests` doesn't care if a provided proxy is valid or not. This makes it almost impossible to tell if something is actually working or not and I'm honestly at a loss for what to do. The documentation on proxies provided by `requests` is very minimal.

My code grabs a User-Agent string and a proxy from a list like so:

```
proxy = {"https": "https://%s:%s@%s" % (USERNAME, PASSWORD, random.choice(PROXY_LIST))}
headers = {"User-Agent": random.choice(USER_AGENT_LIST)}
return partial(requests.get, proxies=proxy, headers=headers)
```

an example of a PROXY_LIST entry: `185.46.87.199:8080`

The issue is that I can change the username, change the password, etc... and `requests` doesn't seem to notice/care. A large portion of all the requests being sent aren't going through a proxy at all. Is there any way to test proxies? See if a request is actually going through a provided proxy? Really any tools for debugging and/or fixing this would be immensely appreciated.

After suggestion by larsks, changed the logging level to DEBUG and got the following output:

```
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): mobile.twitter.com
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET /motivesbylorenr HTTP/1.1" 404 1318
```

unchanged whether auth is correct or incorrect, and no mention of proxy in the debug information. Again, requests are going through my local IP.

Comment: this makes me crazy also ... and Im pretty sure it only works with very basic proxies ... it doesnt work with ~50% of the corporate proxies/ firewalls i encounter ... and I have a hard time debugging it let alone trying to fix it .... often times I just give up

Comment: @JoranBeasley That's... comforting. Should I maybe try just using something other than requests here? Or is this something intrinsic to using proxies?

Comment: I dont know ... but if you find a good answer let me know ... I have yet to find a good proxy solution for python

Comment: @JoranBeasley using another language/environment is totally an option. Python is just my go-to-swiss army knife. Any suggestions as to a better stack for working with proxies?

Comment: python is my goto language also ...  I think we have a simillar program written in c# that can get through their proxies np ... I didnt write the program but im pretty sure they didnt even have to do anything special ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Requests logs debugging information at the `DEBUG` priority, so if you enable debug logging via the `logging` module you can see a variety of diagnostics.  For example:

```
>>> import logging
>>> logging.basicConfig(level='DEBUG')
```

With that in place, I can set run:

```
>>> import requests
>>> s = requests.Session()
>>> s.headers={'user-agent': 'my-test-script'}
>>> s.proxies={'http': 'http://localhost:8123',
... 'https': 'http://localhost:8123'}
>>> s.get('http://mentos.com')
```

And see:

```
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET http://mentos.com/ HTTP/1.1" 301 0
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET http://us.mentos.com HTTP/1.1" 200 32160
<Response [200]>
```

That clearly shows the connection to the proxy.

This is hopefully enough to get you started.  I'm using a `Session`
here, but your solution using `partial` would behave similarly.

Compare the above output to the log message when `requests` is *not* using a proxy:

```
>>> requests.get('http://mentos.com')
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): mentos.com
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 0
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): us.mentos.com
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 10566
<Response [200]>
```

Here, we see the initial connection opened to the remote site, rather
than the proxy, and the `GET` requests do not include the hostname.

**Update**

The above, with HTTPS URLs:

```
>>> response = s.get('https://google.com')
>>> response
<Response [200]>
```

Note that I am setting both the `http` and `https` keys in the `proxies` dictionary.

Comment: I'm sorry, I may be thick, but when using a request there's no indication that a proxy is being used. No change in output when auth is incorrect either. Just shows a direct connection to the destination URL. Can post updated log above.

Comment: this gives more details but as mentioned does not show much about the proxies ...

Comment: I'm not sure what you folks mean.  The very first line of the log output shows `requests` making a connection to the proxy, rather than directly to the requested site.  This seems like sufficient verification that it is (or is not) using the proxy as specified.

Comment: @larsks it seems that if there's any issue with the proxy though that no information is output. I can already tell it's not connecting through the proxy. The real question is why.

Comment: Your question asked "[Is there any way to ...]See if a request is actually going through a provided proxy? Really any tools for debugging and/or fixing this would be immensely appreciated."  I think this addresses both of those questions.  It does not solve the "why isn't requests using my proxy question", but certainly seems apropos to what you have asked.

Comment: That's fair I suppose. It's certainly better than nothing, and it doesn't seem there are any better options here.

Comment: @larsks it's also worth noting that this only works for HTTP, and not for HTTPS. Mentos is one of the rare sites today that maintains a non-https site.

Comment: @larsks it doesn't show connection information though. It will still connect, but doesn't show connection details in the log.

Comment: Ah, right.  I guess for that I would switch to `strace` or possibly `tcpdump`.